# firebase analytics: understanding user engagement

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

[image]

The image is from google blog https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/05/whats-new-with-analytics.html

Engagement per user is 12m 25s.

`game_board` takes up 90.4% of total engagement, however average engagement time is only 0m 54s for the `game_board` .

How should I interpret the numbers?

(avg engagement time x avg engagement count) / 12m 54s = 0.904 for `game_board`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That the average user spends 54 seconds playing something until game over/exit game. One session can have multiple user engagements, i.e. the user restarts the level after game over.

The average user spends 12m 25s in the app, with 90.4% of that time spent on the game_board.